# When I input a fake image from google, it outputs real image. but the test accuracy is 98% on test dataset. what might be the problem?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, classification, resnet

I created a Resnet50 model using transfer learning and  the model gives me 98% validation accuracy and 98% test accuracy. but when I input a fake image from google, it outputs real.

For the test dataset, the output is mostly correct but with input images which are downloaded, it always shows real image.

**my code**

```
base_path = '/Users/Laptop/real-and-fake-faces/real_vs_fake/'

def plot_img(base_path, set_):
    dir_ = os.path.join(base_path, 'train', set_)
    k = 0
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(10,10))
    fig.suptitle(set_ + 'Faces')
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
            img = load_img(os.path.join(dir_, os.listdir(os.path.join(dir_))[k]))          
            ax[j,i].imshow(img)
            ax[j,i].set_title("")
            ax[j,i].axis('off')
            k +=1
  #  fig.tight_layout()
    plt.suptitle(set_ + ' Faces')
    return plt

plot_img(base_path, 'real').show()

plot_img(base_path, 'fake').show()




ig = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
train_flow = ig.flow_from_directory(
    base_path + 'train/',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

ig1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

valid_flow = ig1.flow_from_directory(
    base_path + 'valid/',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

test_flow = ig.flow_from_directory(
    base_path + 'test/',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

train_flow.class_indices



# Creating Model, ResNet-50 :

def build_model():
    densenet = ResNet50(
                        weights='imagenet',
                        include_top=False,
                        input_shape=(128,128,3)
                        )
    model = Sequential([densenet,
                        layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                        layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
                        layers.BatchNormalization(),
                        layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
                        ])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                 )
    return model

model=build_model()
model.summary()



checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.h5',
                             save_best_only=True,
                             verbose=1,
                             mode='min',
                             moniter='val_loss'
                            )
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                              factor=0.2, 
                              patience=3, 
                              verbose=1, 
                              min_delta=0.0001
                             )
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')

callbacks = [checkpoint, reduce_lr, csv_logger]


# Training the Model:

train_steps = 100000//64
valid_steps = 20000//64

history = model.fit(train_flow,
    epochs = 10,
    steps_per_epoch =train_steps,
    validation_data =valid_flow,
    validation_steps = valid_steps,
    callbacks=callbacks
)



# Plotting Accuracy and Loss Graph:

plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'])

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'])
plt.show()



# Confusion Matrix:

y_pred = model.predict(test_flow)

y_test = test_flow.classes

y_pred_labels = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix=confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_labels)
confusion_matrix

Fake=False
Real=True
cm_display = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix, display_labels = [Fake, Real])

cm_display.plot()
plt.show()




# ROC AUC Score, Precision Score and Test Accuracy:

from sklearn import metrics
print("ROC AUC Score:", metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_labels))
print("AP Score:", metrics.average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred_labels))
print()
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred_labels))

_, accu = model.evaluate(test_flow)
print('Final Test Acccuracy = {:.3f}'.format(accu*100))





# Testing for a random image:

import PIL
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open('/Users/Laptop/real-and-fake-faces/real_vs_fake/test/fake/00MZYXAT77.jpg')

im2=im1.resize((128,128))
p1 = np.array(im2)
p1=p1/255
plt.imshow(im1)
p1 = np.expand_dims(p1, axis=0)
p1.shape

op=np.argmax(model.predict(p1),axis=-1)
print(op)
if op== [0]:
    print('Fake Face')
else:
    print("Real Face")







import PIL
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open('/Users/Laptop/Desktop/downloaded faces/1.1.jpg')
im2=im1.resize((128,128))
p1 = np.array(im2)
p1=p1/255
plt.imshow(im1)
p1 = np.expand_dims(p1, axis=0)
p1.shape

op=np.argmax(model.predict(p1),axis=-1)
print(op)
if op== [0]:
    print('Fake Face')
else:
    print("Real Face")
```